# How to get Horizontal two-finger touchpad scrolling working in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-2018-09

Vertical scrolling works just fine for me in Eclipse, and horizontal scrolling works perfectly everywhere else, but for some reason in Eclipse horizontal scrolling just doesn't work. I have to manually move the cursor over and drag the scroll bar at the bottom of my project whenever I want to view a line of code that doesn't fit in the visible area. It's not a major issue, but it does get incredibly annoying. Anyone know how to fix this? I'm on Eclipse version 2018-09 (4.9.0) and Windows 10 version 1803, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Did you get this issue solved somehow?

Comment: Shift + Mouse Scroll does not work, it is really annoying issue, need help

Comment: What about adding an issue at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ ?